# Trying to allow access to my website from a specific link using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am running ubuntu 18.04 with Apache version 2.4 and have one domain and two websites

> domain : this.domain
>
> website1 website.this.domain
>
> website2 web-site.this.domain

i am trying to allow access to website1 ONLY if the link is clicked from website2 this means if you enter website.this.domain from your address bar it would redirect you to website2 otherwise if you came from website2 you will be able to access the page.

My .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond ^{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://web-site.this.domain/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ https://web-site.this.domain [R,L]
```

The code blocks people from accessing directly and allows people that are coming from website2. 
The issue is when people have access it doesn't load the page with all the data i tried to inspect it seems that its showing `Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.` If i remove the rules everything is normal but it will be accessible from outside and inside.

So far i have tried also

```
<If %{HTTP_HOST} !='https://web-site.this.domain'">
Redirect / https://web-site.this.domain
</If>
```

The problem is it doesn't matter where the request is from (direct or through the link) it always redirects me to website2, I have also tried {HTTP_REFERER} still without any success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `https://web-site.this.domain` is not a host name, the host name portion of that URL would be `web-site.this.domain`

Comment: _“The issue is when people have access it doesn't load the page with all the data”_ - you are probably referring to external scripts, stylesheets, images here? Well those have been referred by _your_ main document, so _their_ referrer will of course not be from that other domain, but from your own.

Comment: @CBroe i have just tested this and ended in same results.

Comment: (I wasn’t trying to say that should work, I was just pointing out that the value you used wasn’t a host name to begin with. Knowing the terminology a bit is rather important, otherwise you’ll probably end up doing much more trial & error than necessary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^web\-site\.this\.domain [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,NC]
```